# In LyX, how to put the equation number on the left (instead of the right)?

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

I'm writing an article in LyX v.2.0.6 and am quite new to it. All numbered equations have the equation numbering appearing on the right of the equation. I should, however, place them on the left. Does anyone know how to do this? (e.g. using ERT?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for ERTs, go to Document --> Settings --> Document Class, add `leqno` to the *Custom* class options.